# Universal Turing Machine run on Universal Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, church-turing-thesis

I am curious, what happens if we run Universal Turing Machine on itself?

Comment: Nothing special.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you run a [Lisp interpreter](https://bernsteinbear.com/blog/lisp/12_metacircular/) in Lisp?